# Executing a bash script in Oracle/Sun GridEngine

Tags: variables, sungridengine

I have a script which begins by defining a series of variables, before running a programme with those variables. However, the script is being rejected from Grid Engine (it works on a workstation, but as one component of an array job, it needs to run via SGE) because the variables are being read as commands, resulting in a "Command not found" response.

The error is completely reproduced using the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -M not.real@email.address
#$ -m be
#$ -o /scratch/MScGWAS/Output
#$ -e /scratch/MScGWAS/Errors
#$ -q long.q
#$ -cwd
CHR=$1
CHUNK_START=`printf "%.0f" $2`
CHUNK_END=`printf "%.0f" $3`
```

Output Example:

```
CHR=1: Command not found.
CHUNK_START=1: Command not found.
CHUNK_END=5000000: Command not found.
```

How can I get GridEngine to use bash as the interpreter for this script?

Comment: If they are not defined in the script how is it going to know what they represent?

Comment: How are you actually running this script in practice?

Comment: @idipous: could you clarify what you mean? These are the definitions, the variables are used later in the script

Comment: "command not found" is _not_ given when a variable is merely unset. This is something different.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: The script is submitted to Grid Engine

Comment: Here's an experiment: Copy-and-paste the lines you posted here (out of the web page, not out of your original file) into a new script. Run that script locally on your workstation. See if it reproduces the problem. I'm betting heavily that it won't.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're right, it doesn't do it locally, only on GridEngine

Comment: @user2518990 Then this is a GridEngine problem, not a bash problem, and should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: @user2518990 That's not the point. The point is that it already is a correct bash script, and your problem is with how GridEngine executes it, not with bash, so you shouldn't be asking a "bash" question but a "GridEngine" question.

Comment: Do you know that your SGE server _has_ a bash shell at `/bin/bash` at all? Solaris certainly doesn't have a history of keeping it there.

Comment: ...missed out a line of code :#$-S /bin/sh.

*Insert swear words*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your grid engine cluster is configured with the queues in posix_compliant mode and /bin/csh as the default shell.  In posix_compliant mode the initial #! is ignored and you need to specify the shell via a command line switch or with a suitable #$ directive.
Adding the following line to your script should work:

#$ -S /bin/bash

Answer (score 3):

You are not executing your script with `bash`, but with a different shell (e.g. `tcsh`).